# Why assembly namespace coming twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am calling my business layer project in Web Project. I added refress business layer project to Web. When I call class in BL project, I need to write twice this namespace. I dont know why it is coming.

```
MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.User
```

I suppose to call

```
MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.User
```

In my BL project I defined all classes namespace is `MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer`

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming certain things from the tags that you are using. You are using an assembly written in VB.NET in your other project. VB.NET project properties include an attribute "default namespace" and that might be set with the namespace that you have defined explicitly at the top of your classes. Remove the default namespace (uncheck it) in the project properties and recompile the same.

Answer (score 6):

In VB, the project has a default namespace - and this is applied as a prefix to whatever you write in the source. This is *not* like C#, where the project's default namespace just affects the source code template when you add a new item . So if your project default namespace is `Foo.Bar` and you *also* declare a namespace of `Foo.Bar.Baz`, the full namespace will be `Foo.Bar.Foo.Bar.Baz`.

I suggest you either change the project settings or just remove the common prefix from your source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c#, you can use this code segment :

```
using MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.User = MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.User;
```

So you can use the namespace MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.User instead of MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.User

Regards, 
pro

Answer (score 0):

you can also access the namespace if you start from the global namespace in C# like this:
`global::MyCompanyName.HRHead.DataLayer.User`